# Play a random track on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a fixed image on my page and I want it to play a random sound track upon mouse hover over. This could be 1 of 5 tracks.

This is my HTML `<img src="images/Airplane.png" class="Airplane-photo">`

This is my CSS

```
.Airplane-photo {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 200px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

All my tracks are MP3 and OGG. I have read through this guide but it doesn't help me with what I need: https://css-tricks.com/play-sound-on-hover/

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: where is the code for playing audio?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but you need JavaScript for doing what you want. @Marius answer it's good in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsbin.com/fiyomafuce/2/edit

You make an array of your mp3/ogg paths like:

```
var audio = ["audio-1.mp3", "audio-2.mp3", "audio-3.mp3", "audio-4.mp3", "audio-5.mp3"];
```

This functions returns a random number from 0 to 5, where 5 is `audio.length` so no need to update if you have more mp3

```
function getRandomAudio() {
    var max = audio.length;
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max + 1));
}
```

When the cursor is over the button the audio element will change his source to a new item from the audio array.

```
$btn.on('mouseover', function(){
  var index = getRandomAudio(); // random index
  $audio.attr('src', audio[index]); // change src
  $audio.get(0).play();
});
```

And also if you want to stop the sound when its outside the button you can simply call the mouseout functions like this

```
$btn.on('mouseout', function() { $audio.get(0).pause() });
```

PS. Of course you will not hear anything because the paths are not real.

Comment: Thank you for that Marius.

I have tried implementing it although it doesn't seem to want to work
I have all my sound files stored in a folder named sound. 

This is the code
var audio = ["sound/audio1.mp3", "sound/audio2.mp3", "sound/audio3.mp3", "sound/audio4.mp3", "sound/audio5.mp3", "sound/audio6.mp3"];
var $btn = $('button');
var $audio = $('audio');

function getRandomAudio() {
    var max = audio.length;
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max + 1));
}

$btn.on('mouseover', function(){
  var index = getRandomAudio();
  $audio.attr('sound/', audio[index]);
  $audio.get(0).play();
});

Comment: Btw, have you added <audio></audio> in your HTML?

Comment: Maybe add an ID to audio like <audio id="mySound" and in the javascript replace $audio = $('audio') width $audio = $('#mySound')

Comment: and of course $btn = $('.Airplane-button') in your case

Comment: Would this be correct in trying to get to the source, $audio.attr('sound/', audio[index]);